# Getting multiple variables in URL for JSON

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate, url, servlets

I am trying to retrieve multiple variables in the URL, so I could send a query to database to select a specific object, but it seems that it picks up the first object and others are null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getGroup/{Name}/{StartDate}/{EndDate}/{Status_GroupID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<GroupsDetails> getGroupList(
        @PathVariable String Name, String StartDate, String EndDate,
        Integer Status_GroupID) {

    return musicStoreService.getGroupList(Name, StartDate, EndDate, Status_GroupID);
}
```

The error I am recieving:

```
    Hibernate: select groupsdeta0_.Status_GroupID as Status1_1_, groupsdeta0_.GroupsID as GroupsID1_,        groupsdeta0_.EndDate as EndDate1_, groupsdeta0_.Name as Name1_, groupsdeta0_.StartDate as StartDate1_ from Groups groupsdeta0_ where groupsdeta0_.Name=Gamma and (groupsdeta0_.StartDate is null) and (groupsdeta0_.EndDate is null) and (groupsdeta0_.Status_GroupID is null)
Sep 12, 2014 2:41:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/ATS] threw exception  [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could  not execute query] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Gamma' in 'where clause'
```

The table is named Groups and it has rows : Name, StartDate, EndDate, Status_GroupID and GroupsID

Update:

I am trying to retrieve a primarykey by giving the rows details, but it is not working.

```
@Override
public List<GroupsDetails> getGroupList(String Name, String StartDate, String EndDate, Integer Status_GroupID) {
  SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory();
  Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
  try{
    transaction.begin();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<GroupsDetails> groupList=session.createSQLQuery("FROM Groups WHERE Name=" + Name + " AND StartDate=" + StartDate + " AND EndDate=" + EndDate + " AND Status_GroupID=" + Status_GroupID).list();
    return groupList;
  }finally{
    session.close();
  }
```

}

But it throws the exception that is badly syntax, even tho I can not see the error in syntax.
The error is :

```
Hibernate: FROM Groups WHERE Name=Gamma AND StartDate=01-06-2014 AND EndDate=01-09-2014 AND Status_GroupID=1
Sep 12, 2014 3:35:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/ATS] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Groups WHERE Name=Gamma AND StartDate=01-06-2014 AND EndDate=01-09-2014 AND' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error details :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM Groups WHERE Name=Gamma AND StartDate=01-06-2014 AND EndDate=01-09-2014 AND' at line 1
```

it clearly shows that you are missing quotes, eg: `Name=Gamma` should be `Name='Gamma'`

Alternatively you can create the `Query` by using [Parameters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#d5e8463) for example:

```
query = sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Groups 
        WHERE NAME=:name  AND StartDate=:startDate AND EndDate=:endDate 
        AND Status_GroupID=:status_GroupID").addEntity(Groups.class);

   query.setString("name", name);
   query.setDate("startDate", StartDate);
   query.setString("endDate", EndDate);
   query.setString("status_GroupID", Status_GroupID);


List<GroupsDetails> groupList = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have @PathVariable infront of all parameters. Like

```
public @ResponseBody List<GroupsDetails> getGroupList(
        @PathVariable String Name, @PathVariable String StartDate, @PathVariable String EndDate,
        @PathVariable Integer Status_GroupID)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but now I have another problem. If its possible could you give it a look?